# Rename a generated file in Maven before building WAR

Tags: java, maven, css-sprites

Fingers crossed you can help me!

I am using [SmartSprites](http://csssprites.org/) to combine the PNGs on my landing page into one, so that it will load quicker.

SmartSprite will examine your CSS files, generate a CSS Sprite image, and create a new CSS file which will use this sprite image instead of the originals.  What I want to do is replace the original CSS file with the SmartSprite one automatically during my maven WAR build.

So here's what I would like to happen:

1. SmartSprite scans my CSS file: *mystyle.css*
2. SmartSprite create a sprite image, and creates a new *mystyle-sprite.css* file, which references the new sprite image.
3. **I want to copy *mystyle-sprite.css* over *mystyle.css* before the WAR is built, so that I don't have to change any of my references in the JSP files.**

Both files are located in the output directory (target/myproj/css).  There doesn't seem to be any flag in SmartSprite to override the original file, so I guess it had to be done post-processing.

Below is the maven plugin configuration I'm using for SmartSprite.

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.carrot2.labs</groupId>
            <artifactId>smartsprites-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>1.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>spritify</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [Maven WAR plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/war-mojo.html):

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
        <webResources>
            <resource>
                <directory><!-- Your output directory --></directory>
                <targetPath><!-- The target location of the files below --></targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include><!-- file pattern --></include>
                    <include><!-- file pattern --></include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </webResources>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

You should also configure SmartSprites to use a different output directory to preserve the original CSS filename. Try the `output-dir-path` option with an empty `css-file-suffix` value.

Comment: Hi Ates, How would I rename a file from mystyle-sprite.css to mystyle.css using the resources?  I thought that could only either include or exclude a file, but not change its name during transfer.

Comment: @JohnFarrelly Updated my answer. Try using a different output directory (one that's different from the WAR's default scratch area).

Comment: And, oh yes, this will work. I'm using this method for a slightly different scenario (RequireJS optimization of JS + CSS files).

Comment: Thanks Ates.  I had to write my own maven plugin to explicitly pass down an empty css-file-suffix, but it works a treat after that!

Comment: This snippet does not rename the file. The Maven War Plugin does not allow that.

Answer (score 20):

I'm afraid you won't find anything simpler or more elegant than Maven AntRun Plugin with something like this:

```xml
<build>
  <plugins>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
      <version>1.7</version>
      <executions>
        <execution>
          <phase>prepare-package</phase>
          <configuration>
            <target>
              <copy file="${project.build.directory}/mystyle-sprite.css"
                tofile="${project.build.directory}/mystyle.css" />
            </target>
          </configuration>
          <goals>
            <goal>run</goal>
          </goals>
        </execution>
      </executions>
    </plugin>
  </plugins>
</build>
```

Comment: Maybe you should move the file instead of copying. You don't want to leave behind build artifacts in your final WAR.

Comment: Not a problem. Replace `<copy ... />` task with `<move file="file.orig" tofile="file.moved" />`. Question was about copying.

Comment: Regarding renaming files without using assembly this should be the accepted answer - just saved my day :-)